# Passing Data from Controler to HTML Template

Tags: angularjs, controller, components, angular1.6

I need to pass data from controller to html template. I can see the data from console.log but I don't see the it through the DOM.

This my COMPONENT:

```
import ItemService from '../../services/test.service.js'

const TestComponent = {
    controllerAs: 'testCtrl',
    controller: function ($http) {
                    ItemService.getItems($http)
                    .then(data => {
                        this.items = data.categories;
                        console.log('inside controller', this.items);
                        })
    },
    template: require('./test.html'),
    bindings: {

    }
};

export default TestComponent;
```

AND this is the template :./test.html

```
<div class="test">
    NAMES OF ITEMS:
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in testCtrl.items">
          <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Why don't I see the list?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the context of `this` might have changed in the callback of $http. It is not pointing towards your controller anymore.

Try storing a reference to the controller context in a local variable (Eg: `self`):

```
var self = this;
ItemService.getItems($http)
.then(data => {
    self.items = data.categories;
    console.log('inside controller', self.items);
})
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Actually the data at the console is good. I think my problem got to do with the reactivity of the data. Maybe you can clarify that

Comment: Yes but you are binding it to a different context so the console log will still work inside the http callback. Can you put a breakpoint inside the 'then' callback and check if 'this' is refering to your controller?

Comment: I got that 'this' is related to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If **this** is your controller and still doesn't shows up, maybe the data is not being digested by the scope, a common thing with promises in angularjs, you need to force with `$scope.$digest()` after the asign, or

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
//assign inside here
});
```

this can cause problems if you are in the middle of one digest cycle, so the better way to do this is with $timeout:

```
$timeout(() => {
//assign here
});
```